# Query to count all rows in all Snowflake views

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to get an count of all the rows in a set of views in my Snowflake database.

The built-in `row_count` from `information_schema.tables` is not present in `information_schema.views`, unfortunately.

It seems I'd need to `count` all rows in each view, something like:

```sql
with view_name as (select table_name 
    from account_usage.views
    where table_schema = 'ACCESS' and RIGHT(table_name,7) = 'CURRENT'
                  )
select count (*) from view_name;
```

But that returns only one results, instead of one for each line

If I change the `select` to include the view name, i.e.

```sql
select concat('Rows in ', view_name), count (*) from view_name;
```

…it returns the error *"invalid identifier 'VIEW_NAME' (line 5)"*

How can I show all results and include the view name?

Comment: Have you looked into an SP?  The SP could iterate over the `information_schema.views`, run each count for those views, and then insert the results into a table, and then you can query the table after the SP populates the information.

Comment: I did, but this is a DWH setup where I don't want to use any SPs. Plus, I'd still need to code to iterate, just in a different format.

Comment: For now, I just did it manually for the 10 or so tables that I cared about. Still interested in an automation.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a query that looks at the information_schema to create a query that will go view by view getting its count:

```sql
select listagg(xx, ' union all ')
from (
    select 'select count(*) c, \'' || x || '\' v from ' || x as xx
    from (
        select TABLE_CATALOG ||'.'|| TABLE_SCHEMA ||'."'||TABLE_NAME||'"' x
        from  KNOEMA_FORECAST_DATA_ATLAS.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
        where table_schema='FORECAST'
    )
)
```

See also [How to find the number of rows for all views in a schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66116474/how-to-find-the-number-of-rows-for-all-views-in-a-schema/66116475)